# how to add icon and Image in Tabhost android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabbar, android-framelayout, tabwidget

I am following [this](http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/android-app-development-tabbed-activities/) tutorial to add icon along with text using Tabhost.

I am writting following codes to add text and icon in tab .

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));

    TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));

    TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home));
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);
}
```

It works fine with adding text only in tab but throws following error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content at android.widget.TabHost.addTab
```

need some help here  please...

Comment: can you able to post the whole error log ?

Comment: sure...my error looks like this http://i.imgur.com/UPoDCv3.jpg

Comment: Do you see your  TabSpec spec2, you are not setting  setContent spec2.. You are setting spec 1 again ,i cant find any other issues.

Comment: Thank you Sree for pointing out  but the image icon in Tab is not still showing up ...I am getting following result http://imgur.com/1LqqdMq

Answer (score 2):

Create a selector xml store it in drawable folder and try this code :

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent().setClass(this,YourClass.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_name").setIndicator("Tab Text", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_selector)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Xml for selector name it tab_selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_unselected" />
</selector>
```

ic_tab_selected and ic_tab_unselected these are the icon image which will be shown on selecting and deselecting the tab

Comment: what is the purpose of  Intent().setClass(this,YourClass.class);  @Clairvoyant ....its throwing  IllegalStateException. in my case